# [RAILS]: Display a multiple category checkbox in a product form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, form-for, join

I'm new on Ror, 
I developp an app where you can choose multiple categories for a product.
I try to add in my Product form a multiple checkbox for pre-selected categories but I don't succeed to display it. I have a model for Category and a model for Product and also a jointable between both of them.

```
create_table "categories_products", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "category_id", null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
```

I don't succeed to display the pre-selected choice checkbox in my form.  I need some help. Thk in advance.
Here is my code:
app/models/category.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :products, dependent: :destroy
```

app/models/product.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

Product Controller.rb:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, category_ids:[ ])
```

views/products/_form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <%= form_for @product, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h5>Détails projet:</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nom du projet (max. 20 caractères)</label>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Nom du projet", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label "Categorie de projet:" %><br />
          <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
          <div class=« collection-check-box">
            <%= b.check_box %>
            <%= b.label %>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Valider le projet", class: 'btn btn-md btn-danger' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, that should work

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <% b.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {b.check_box(class: "checkbox") + b.text } %>
<% end %>
```

You can see the [API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) for more options

Comment: Thk you @fool-dev but I still don't have my input appearing in my form  for the product categories :-(

Comment: I got it :-) thks fool-dev